# Issue with spring context for rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

At **rabit:template** I have problem with seting **rabbit:reply-listener** error message is:

> cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'rabbit:template' must have no character
>   or element information item [children], because the type's content
>   type is empty.

I'm trying to set this conext to handle **convertSendAndReceive** method of **RabbitTemplate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
    https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-amqp/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/resources/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnFactory"
    username="${rabbitmq.user}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" host="${rabbitmq.host}" port="${rabbitmq.port}" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="rabbitQueue" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="rabbitExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="rabbitQueue" pattern="camel" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>


<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" 
    connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" exchange="rabbitExchange" routing-key="camel" >
    <rabbit:reply-listener />
</rabbit:template>

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" concurrency="10">
    <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitMessageListener" method="createDongleIncident"
        queue-names="rabbitQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="rabbitMessageListener" class="com.bosch.mome.dongle.listener.DongleQueueListener" />
```

Comment: Why on earth are you referencing a wrong XSD? Just use the correct namespace .. Use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd` instead of the github one you use now.

Comment: ok, I understand, but then I have at every rabbit:something error `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'rabbit:connection-factory'.`

Comment: IN your IDE or runtime? If eclipse is your IDE ignore it, imho it handles namespaces badly. Spring loads the xsd from the jar files ion your classpath. So if the spring rabbit stuff is on your classpath it will run. If you want to fix it in eclipse use STS or teach it where to find the xsd in the jar.

Comment: To be honest I did not check build in console. Proper namespace helped, thank you